# Сложный запрос Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы с более чем миллионом записей в каждой:

```
shop_items (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
division_id int(11) NOT NULL,
divisions varchar(255) NOT NULL,
art varchar(255) NOT NULL,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


shop_items_rows_values (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_row int(11) NOT NULL,
id_item int(11) NOT NULL,
value text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Как ускорить выполнение подобного запроса (выполняется около 3-4 часов)

```
"select shop_items.id, brand.value as brandvalue, material.value as materialvalue, cvet.value as cvetvalue, size.value as sizevalue, sizes.value as sizesvalue from shop_items 
                        Left JOIN shop_items_rows_values as brand on brand.id_item = shop_items.id and brand.id_row = '5'
                        Left JOIN shop_items_rows_values as material on material.id_item = shop_items.id and material.id_row = '3'
                        Left JOIN shop_items_rows_values as cvet on cvet.id_item = shop_items.id and cvet.id_row = '7'
                        Left JOIN shop_items_rows_values as size on size.id_item = shop_items.id and size.id_row = '4'
                        Left JOIN shop_items_rows_values as sizes on sizes.id_item = shop_items.id and sizes.id_row = '6'
                        where archive = '0'"
```

Comment: Поставить индекс на **id_row, id_item** не вариант?

Comment: К тому же не вижу в структуре поля **archive**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать это можно как-то так

```
ALTER TABLE `shop_items_rows_values`
    ADD INDEX `id_row` (`id_row`),
    ADD INDEX `id_item` (`id_item`);
```

Или комбинированный в зависимости от того где еще и как используются у вас **id_row** и **id_item**

```
ALTER TABLE `shop_items_rows_values`
    ADD INDEX `id_row_id_item` (`id_row`, `id_item`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил попробовать переписать ваш запрос так:

```
 select shop_items.id,
        max(if(V.id_row=5, V.value, NULL)) as brandvalue,
        max(if(V.id_row=3, V.value, NULL)) as materialvalue,
        max(if(V.id_row=7, V.value, NULL)) as cvetvalue,
        max(if(V.id_row=4, V.value, NULL)) as sizevalue,
        max(if(V.id_row=6, V.value, NULL)) as sizesvalue
   from shop_items
   left join shop_items_rows_values as V
     on V.id_item = shop_items.id and V.id_row in('3','4','5','6','7')
  where archive = '0'
  group by shop_items.id
```

И построить индекс по id_item по таблице с значениями, если его вдруг нет. При этом, если возможных значений id_row в таблице гораздо больше и они целые числа - то есть смысл делать составной индекс по (id_item, id_row) и условие в ON задать в виде `V.id_row between 3 and 7`.